# Community eval — Feb 2013

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

Here are the results of the February 2013 community evaluation. You can comment them in this thread.

Voici les résultats de l'évaluation communautaire de février 2013. Ce fil est destiné à recevoir vos commentaires.

`Ex Sa NI sc`
 7  4  0  7    [Comment traduire « relatives » et « parents ». Ambiguïté ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4586/comment-traduire-relatives-et-parents-ambiguite)
 6  5  0  6    [Quel est la différence d'usage entre « nous » et « on » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4601/quel-est-la-difference-dusage-entre-nous-et-on)
 3  7  1  2    [Traduction de « it takes two to tango »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4491/traduction-de-it-takes-two-to-tango)
 6  4  1  5    [Comment traduire « what has been seen cannot be unseen » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4505/comment-traduire-what-has-been-seen-cannot-be-unseen)
 9  2  0  9    [Que veut dire « manger la feuille » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4508/que-veut-dire-manger-la-feuille)
 5  7  1  4    [What does the expression "Oh, là, là" mean?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4513/what-means-the-expression-oh-la-la)
 7  4  1  6    [How to understand "c'est l'affaire de tous"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4524/how-to-understand-cest-laffaire-de-tous)
 1  7  4 ‒3    [How to translate "so to speak"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4563/how-to-translate-so-to-speak)
 6  6  0  6    [« Frapper à la bonne porte » ou « frapper la bonne porte » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4572/frapper-a-la-bonne-porte-ou-frapper-la-bonne-porte)
 6  6  0  6    [French equivalent of "just in case"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4607/french-equivalent-of-just-in-case)

<sub>`Ex`/`Sa`/`NI`: number of “excellent/satisfactory/needs improvement” ratings</sub> 
 <sup>`sc`: total score</sup>

Comment: Ça correspond à quoi? J'ai pensé à la possibilité de voter des non inscrits, mais si _Ex_ serait alors un vote positif et _NI_ un vote négatif, je ne vois pas d'où proviendrait le _Sa_.

Comment: @Unfrancophone De quel « ça » parles-tu ? `sc`=`Ex`-`NI`, les `Sa` sont ignorés dans le score. Je ne sais pas si c'est la question.

Comment: Des valeurs.  J'avais déduit la manière dont _sc_ est calculée et si _Ex_ et _NI_ peuvent être le résultat des votes des non-inscrits, je ne vois pas à quoi correspond _Sa_.